# What can I do for the clone() method?

Tags: java, clone

if I have a code which has the clone() method but as I know that the duplicate code is bad here(in that application e.g.bank Application),what should I do???
the clone() method is in the bankOfAmerica which implements IAccount(IAccount has the clone() method header!)One person has override the clone() method in the bankOfAmerica class and I don't want to make duplicate code here.what should I do with that clone() method.

clone() method:

```
public IAccount clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
      return (BankOfIranSavingsAccount) super.clone();
}
```

Comment: Wait what? you have a code? Are you asking if the clone method is ok to use or are you asking about duplicate code?

Comment: Definitely need some clarification on what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Please include bad code along with a description of what's wrong with it.

Comment: Please tell me you are not working for my bank ;)

Comment: @ all:there is code with this clone() method:public IAccount clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
   return (BankOfIranSavingsAccount) super.clone();
  }

Comment: Please, Johanna, edit the question and put the code there.

Comment: so, what are you asking about it? it calls the super version. Are you asking if that method is unnecessary?

Comment: -1 if the question is clarified I'll undo it.

Answer (score 1):

Returning 'super.clone()' as the implementation of clone is almost guaranteed to be wrong.  If you look at [clone](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29)'s javadoc, you'll see that the expectation is that if b is a clone of a, then the following should typically be true

```
a != b;
a.getClass() == b.getClass();
a.equals(b);
```

While these aren't hard and fast rules, and the *meaning* of clone is really dependent on the implementing class, you should have a really good reason, preferably well documented, if your implementation doesn't meet these expectations.  And in general, any clone method that calls super.clone() to create its return value will fail the second test.

Comment: I would suggest that the right pattern is for clone methods to devolve to object.clone, in which case cloning methods which call super.clone will meet the second criterion.  Unfortunately, a lot of cloning methods use a constructor rather than calling Object.Clone, and thus calling super.Clone with such objects would return an object of the wrong type.